# Prove that this limit is the logarithmic derivative of the Riemann zeta function.

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, riemann-zeta

> Prove the following limit:
>
> $$-\frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)}=\lim_{c\to 1} \, \left(\frac{\zeta (c)
>  \zeta (s)}{\zeta (c+s-1)}-\zeta (c)\right)$$

As a starting point I tried to enter this series expansion line in Mathematica:

```
Series[Zeta[s]*Zeta[c]/Zeta[s + c - 1] - Zeta[c], {c, 1, 0}]
```

which expanded at $c=1$ gives me:

$$-\frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)}+O\left((c-1)^1\right)$$

But I don't know how to do series expansions.

Comment: This seems to follow directly from $$\lim_{c\to1}(c-1)\zeta(c)=1.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. assume $\zeta(s) \neq0$. One may recall that, as $c \to 1$,
$$
(c-1)\zeta(c)=1+O(c-1) \tag1
$$ then, by the Taylor series expansion, as $c \to 1$, one has
$$
\zeta(c+s-1)=\zeta(s)+\zeta'(s)(c-1)+O((c-1)^2)
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\zeta (c)
 \zeta (s)}{\zeta (c+s-1)}-\zeta (c)&=\left(\frac{\zeta (s)}{\zeta (c+s-1)}-1\right)\zeta (c) 
\\\\&=\left(\frac{\zeta (s)}{\zeta(s)+\zeta'(s)(c-1)+O((c-1)^2)}-1\right)\zeta (c) 
\\\\&=\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}(c-1)+O((c-1)^2)}-1\right)\zeta (c)
\\\\&=\left(-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}(c-1)+O((c-1)^2)\right)\zeta (c)
\\\\&=-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}(c-1)\zeta (c)+O((c-1)^2\zeta (c))
\\\\& \to -\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}
\end{align}
$$ as announced.